# Is there any way in React to pass an elementType through spread properties?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-bootstrap

This works to create Nav.Link as react-router-dom Link:

```
<Nav.Link as={Link} to='/'>link</Nav.Link>
```

But this:

```
const props = { as: { Link }, to: '/' }
return (
  <Nav.Link {...props}>link</Nav.Link>
)
```

fails with:

```
Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.

Check the render method of `ForwardRef`.
```

My Nav.Link is in a component library that doesn't have a dependency on react-router, and I was hoping to pass in the 'as={Link}' from the main app without forcing that dependency onto the library.

Comment: Try this: `const props = { as: Link, to: '/' }`

Answer (score 0):

D'oh! Figured it out!

```
const props = { as: Link, to: '/' }
return (
  <Nav.Link {...props}>link</Nav.Link>
)
```